# How will I be able to make the elements generate a code for my website builder?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently developing a website builder with javascript and html canvas. I am now puzzled on what my next step will be. I am done with the drag, drop, resize functions. But I want it to generate a code when I drop an element on a certain form(pretty much like how visual basic IDE works). How will I make the elements generate a code?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>DnD initial</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="shapes.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #95a5a6;">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

shapes.js

```
function Shape(state, x, y, w, h, fill) {
  "use strict";

  this.state = state;
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  this.w = w || 1;
  this.h = h || 1;
  this.fill = fill || '#AAAAAA';
}

// Draws this shape to a given context
Shape.prototype.draw = function(ctx, optionalColor) {
  "use strict";
  var i, cur, half;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  if (this.state.selection === this) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.state.selectionColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.state.selectionWidth;
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);


    half = this.state.selectionBoxSize / 2;


    this.state.selectionHandles[0].x = this.x-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[0].y = this.y-half;

    this.state.selectionHandles[1].x = this.x+this.w/2-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[1].y = this.y-half;

    this.state.selectionHandles[2].x = this.x+this.w-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[2].y = this.y-half;


    this.state.selectionHandles[3].x = this.x-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[3].y = this.y+this.h/2-half;


    this.state.selectionHandles[4].x = this.x+this.w-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[4].y = this.y+this.h/2-half;


    this.state.selectionHandles[6].x = this.x+this.w/2-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[6].y = this.y+this.h-half;

    this.state.selectionHandles[5].x = this.x-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[5].y = this.y+this.h-half;

    this.state.selectionHandles[7].x = this.x+this.w-half;
    this.state.selectionHandles[7].y = this.y+this.h-half;


    ctx.fillStyle = this.state.selectionBoxColor;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
      cur = this.state.selectionHandles[i];
      ctx.fillRect(cur.x, cur.y, this.state.selectionBoxSize, this.state.selectionBoxSize);
    }
  }
};


Shape.prototype.contains = function(mx, my) {
  "use strict";

  return  (this.x <= mx) && (this.x + this.w >= mx) &&
          (this.y <= my) && (this.y + this.h >= my);
};

function CanvasState(canvas) {
  "use strict";


  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop,
      html, myState, i;
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    this.stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).paddingLeft, 10)      || 0;
    this.stylePaddingTop  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).paddingTop, 10)       || 0;
    this.styleBorderLeft  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).borderLeftWidth, 10)  || 0;
    this.styleBorderTop   = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).borderTopWidth, 10)   || 0;
  }

  html = document.body.parentNode;
  this.htmlTop = html.offsetTop;
  this.htmlLeft = html.offsetLeft;


  this.valid = false; 
  this.shapes = [];  
  this.dragging = false; 
  this.resizeDragging = false; 
  this.expectResize = -1; 

  this.selection = null;
  this.dragoffx = 0; 
  this.dragoffy = 0;

  this.selectionHandles = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    this.selectionHandles.push(new Shape(this));
  }

  myState = this;


  canvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var mouse, mx, my, shapes, l, i, mySel;
    if (myState.expectResize !== -1) {
      myState.resizeDragging = true;
      return;
    }
    mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    mx = mouse.x;
    my = mouse.y;
    shapes = myState.shapes;
    l = shapes.length;
    for (i = l-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      if (shapes[i].contains(mx, my)) {
        mySel = shapes[i];

        myState.dragoffx = mx - mySel.x;
        myState.dragoffy = my - mySel.y;
        myState.dragging = true;
        myState.selection = mySel;
        myState.valid = false;
        return;
      }
    }

    if (myState.selection) {
      myState.selection = null;
      myState.valid = false; 
    }
  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mouse = myState.getMouse(e),
        mx = mouse.x,
        my = mouse.y,
        oldx, oldy, i, cur;
    if (myState.dragging){
      mouse = myState.getMouse(e);

      myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragoffx;
      myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragoffy;   
      myState.valid = false; 
    } else if (myState.resizeDragging) {

      oldx = myState.selection.x;
      oldy = myState.selection.y;

      // 0  1  2
      // 3     4
      // 5  6  7
      switch (myState.expectResize) {
        case 0:
          myState.selection.x = mx;
          myState.selection.y = my;
          myState.selection.w += oldx - mx;
          myState.selection.h += oldy - my;
          break;
        case 1:
          myState.selection.y = my;
          myState.selection.h += oldy - my;
          break;
        case 2:
          myState.selection.y = my;
          myState.selection.w = mx - oldx;
          myState.selection.h += oldy - my;
          break;
        case 3:
          myState.selection.x = mx;
          myState.selection.w += oldx - mx;
          break;
        case 4:
          myState.selection.w = mx - oldx;
          break;
        case 5:
          myState.selection.x = mx;
          myState.selection.w += oldx - mx;
          myState.selection.h = my - oldy;
          break;
        case 6:
          myState.selection.h = my - oldy;
          break;
        case 7:
          myState.selection.w = mx - oldx;
          myState.selection.h = my - oldy;
          break;
      }

      myState.valid = false; 
    }


    if (myState.selection !== null && !myState.resizeDragging) {
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {


        cur = myState.selectionHandles[i];

        if (mx >= cur.x && mx <= cur.x + myState.selectionBoxSize &&
            my >= cur.y && my <= cur.y + myState.selectionBoxSize) {

          myState.expectResize = i;
          myState.valid = false;

          switch (i) {
            case 0:
              this.style.cursor='nw-resize';
              break;
            case 1:
              this.style.cursor='n-resize';
              break;
            case 2:
              this.style.cursor='ne-resize';
              break;
            case 3:
              this.style.cursor='w-resize';
              break;
            case 4:
              this.style.cursor='e-resize';
              break;
            case 5:
              this.style.cursor='sw-resize';
              break;
            case 6:
              this.style.cursor='s-resize';
              break;
            case 7:
              this.style.cursor='se-resize';
              break;
          }
          return;
        }

      }

      myState.resizeDragging = false;
      myState.expectResize = -1;
      this.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    myState.dragging = false;
    myState.resizeDragging = false;
    myState.expectResize = -1;
    if (myState.selection !== null) {
      if (myState.selection.w < 0) {
          myState.selection.w = -myState.selection.w;
          myState.selection.x -= myState.selection.w;
      }
      if (myState.selection.h < 0) {
          myState.selection.h = -myState.selection.h;
          myState.selection.y -= myState.selection.h;
      }
    }
  }, true);

  canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
    var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    myState.addShape(new Shape(myState, mouse.x - 10, mouse.y - 10, 20, 20, '#bdc3c7'));
  }, true);


  this.selectionColor = '#3498db';
  this.selectionWidth = 2;  
  this.selectionBoxSize = 6;
  this.selectionBoxColor = '#2980b9';
  this.interval = 30;
  setInterval(function() { myState.draw(); }, myState.interval);
}

CanvasState.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
  "use strict";
  this.shapes.push(shape);
  this.valid = false;
};

CanvasState.prototype.clear = function() {
  "use strict";
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};


CanvasState.prototype.draw = function() {
  "use strict";
  var ctx, shapes, l, i, shape, mySel;

  if (!this.valid) {
    ctx = this.ctx;
    shapes = this.shapes;
    this.clear();


    l = shapes.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
      shape = shapes[i];

      if (shape.x <= this.width && shape.y <= this.height &&
          shape.x + shape.w >= 0 && shape.y + shape.h >= 0) {
        shapes[i].draw(ctx);
      }
    }


    if (this.selection !== null) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectionColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = this.selectionWidth;
      mySel = this.selection;
      ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x,mySel.y,mySel.w,mySel.h);
    }


    this.valid = true;
  }
};



CanvasState.prototype.getMouse = function(e) {
  "use strict";
  var element = this.canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, mx, my;


  if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
    do {
      offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
      offsetY += element.offsetTop;
      element = element.offsetParent;
    } while (element);
  }


  offsetX += this.stylePaddingLeft + this.styleBorderLeft + this.htmlLeft;
  offsetY += this.stylePaddingTop + this.styleBorderTop + this.htmlTop;

  mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
  my = e.pageY - offsetY;


  return {x: mx, y: my};
};


function init() {
  "use strict";
  var s = new CanvasState(documen// add a large green rectangle
  s.addShape(new Shape(s, 260, 70, 60, 65, 'rgba(0,205,0,0.7)'));

  s.addShape(new Shape(s, 240, 120, 40, 40, 'rgba(2,165,165,0.7)'));  

  s.addShape(new Shape(s, 5, 60, 25, 25, 'rgba(150,150,250,0.7)'));
}
```

Comment: A short question to get a sense of complexity: do all elements end up directly on your canvas, or do you have child-elements of any kind?.

Comment: They are dragged and dropped on the same canvas. What do you mean by child-elements?

Comment: No child-elements by my interpretation then. I was referring to, for example, 2 Rectangles that are positioned within an outer rectangle, which would have made the problem a little harder to solve :).

Comment: You mean like when I drag a header(big rectangle) on the form(a bigger rectangle which represents the website) and when I drag a button(small rectangle) on the header that I just dragged? If yes, then I do have child-elements :(

Comment: @KYOUMAH hi -  I'm not sure what you're asking - "How will I make the elements generate a code?" .. do you mean generate a unique Id number for each element ?

Comment: @user2808054 What I mean is that, to automatically generate a code after dropping an element on a form. For instance, I dropped a button on the form, a text file or any file must be automatically produced and it should contain something like "<button>Button's Text</button>"

Comment: edited the title, sorry xD

Comment: If this help you.

I have done a form generation program before with Javascript. I have used a div as the container. When i pick a control from the tool bar, say a button what i did was i add the div.innerHTML+="<input type='button"... This will add a button to the div and when you move it dynamically change the top and left value in style. But in canvas I am not sure what can be done.

Comment: Just generate the html when you drop an element and append it to a string, when you are finished you output the string. (The hard part is nested element, but that depens on your code and how you implemented the drag and drag function) So if we can't see how you did it, we can't help.

Comment: Seeing code is almost necessary to your question. But without code,  here's a quick narrative overview: First, save the x,y position, the z-index (order added to the canvas?) and any parent-child relationships between your elements.  Presumably you are listening to mouse events to enable dragging. In mouseup you should regenerate all your html from the saved information.

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat Thanks, I'll try that one. But a little more detail might help :D

Comment: @KYOUMAH: Give me your email Id. I Can sent you the file. Its a little big for copy paste.

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat crossazure@rocketmail.com THanks in advance :D

Comment: @KYOUMAH: I have send u the mail

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat Thanks but I can't access my mail for the moment. Could you send it to me via dropbox or facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- get the element which has been dragged & dropped
- get the target element onto which the new element will be placed
- add that element to the child of the target element

something like ...

```
var elSource= (whatever element was dragged & dropped - will leave you to work that out);
var elTarget = (target element of drag & drop - presumably you can find that)
var elClone=elSource.cloneNode(true); // makes a copy of source node
elTarget.appendChild(elClone); // adds the cloned html element to 'inside' the target element
```

See [w3cSchools.com DOM element object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) for info

Comment: Thanks, I just posted my code. I'll try this one out :)